# What are considered atoms in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

Can someone please explain or link me to any helpful resources ( I couldn't find any threads on google) that could help me understand what atoms are.

Comment: Better use the term [first class values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen).

Answer (score 20):

Nowadays we consider an *atom* an element that's not a cons-pair and that is not null. That includes:

- Numbers
- Strings
- Symbols
- Booleans
- Characters

This is best expressed with the following procedure, taken from the book The Little Schemer:

```
(define atom?
  (lambda (x)
    (and (not (pair? x)) (not (null? x)))))
```

Comment: "atom" is not a very useful concept. Would a vector be an atom? I would consider it not to be, because it can contain other "atoms", just like a pair. And then there are record types, SRFI-4 vectors (u8vectors are very close to strings but still consist of numbers, conceptually, which are "atoms") etc.  Within the context of the Little Schemer it makes sense, because it concerns itself only with symbols, lists and procedure objects (but very indirectly).

Comment: Does an empty list () considered as an atom ? Btw, chicken scheme built-in `(atom? '())` returns true.

Comment: According to the above definition no, an empty list is not an atom. Don't spend too much time on this, the "atom" concept is not very useful in real life, it's more of an academic concept.

Comment: `atom` is from the original LISP paper from when there was two data types. It was either a cons pair or a symbol. `nil` is a symbol so it is an atom, but Scheme split up the boolean `#f`, the symbol `nil`, and the empty list `'()` and it could go any way and ended up not being an `atom`. In my Lisp Zozotez I have `s` as a way to differentiate between the two types symbol and pair and has the same function. Modern Scheme/CL code should use `pair?`/`consp` and `null?`/`endp`

Comment: Your list does not match the implementation of `atom?`. Procedures are missing.

Answer (score 3):

The term "atom" is used by several authors (McCarthy and Friedman/Felleisen, among others) to refer to a datum that is not a "cons" pair. I claim that these days, you'd be more likely to invert that, and test for "cons"-hood rather than "atom"-hood.  Where are you seeing the term used?