# Lisp in Small Pieces. chapter 1

Tags: lisp, racket

I began to study the book "Lisp in Small Pieces". For examples, the selected Racket. But in the first chapter there is a code sample  (if (atom? e) . What is "atom?"? Where to define it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are considered atoms in Scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609803/what-are-considered-atoms-in-scheme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scheme standard does not define `atom?`; the usual definition is

```
(define (atom? x) 
  (and (not (pair? x))
       (not (null? x))))
```

Comment: And does not define "pair?". How to define "pair?". My DrRacket 5.3. write "2:13: pair?: this function is not defined in: pair?"

Comment: @TophydAyur DrRacket is a compiler/interpreter/IDE for tons of Scheme dialects/cusins. What language are you using? You see it on the line in the interactions windows starting with "Language: ..."

Comment: I chose a mode of student. And what is necessary to make a choice? I'm a newbie.

Comment: Do note though, that in Common Lisp, the empty list `()` and the symbol `nil` are the same, so `()` _is_ an atom.  In Common Lisp, `atom` is just `(not (consp x))`.  (I point this out only because the book is about various dialects, and other dialects might have similar behavior.)  The version you've shown could be simplified by defining `list?` as `(or (pair? x) (null? x))` and then defining `atom?` as `(not (list? x))`, which would make the Common Lisp and Scheme definitions have a bit more in common.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor On page 4 of the mentioned book `(atom? exp)` is indeed explicitly defined as `(not (pair? exp))`. I personally find it rather confusing to mix Scheme-like predicate naming with Common Lisp definitions. Makes me wonder if Racket is a good choice for this endeavour. And why on Earth haven't I still found the time to read that book myself? ;-)

Comment: @uselpa Indeed, I don't advocate mixing the naming conventions;  I was just pointing out the implementation similarity.  I haven't read Lisp In Small Pieces, myself.  Sometimes I really appreciate `()` also being the symbol `nil` (and it explains the name of the predicate `null?`, but sometimes it feels much cleaner to do what Scheme does and have a special empty list that's _not_ a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick mention on page 4 that `(atom? exp)` means `(not (pair? exp))`

Quote from the book:

```
(define (evaluate exp env)
  (if (atom? exp) ; (atom? exp) ≡ (not (pair? exp))
      ...
      (case (car exp)
        ...
        (else ...) ) ) )
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541