# Getting every nth atom using scheme does not pick up the last atom

Tags: scheme

The program is suppose to pick out every third atom in a list.
Notice that the last atom 'p' should be picked up, but its not.
Any suggestions as to why the last atom is not being selected.

```
(define (every3rd lst)
 (if (or (null? lst)            
      (null? (cdr lst)))     
  '()                        
  (cons (car lst)            
        (every3rd (cdr(cdr(cdr lst)))))))


(every3rd '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p))

Value 1: (a d g j m)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a couple of base cases:

```
(define (every3rd lst)
  (cond ((or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst))) lst)
        ((null? (cdr (cdr lst))) (list (car lst)))
        (else (cons (car lst)
                    (every3rd (cdr (cdr (cdr lst))))))))
```

See how the following cases should be handled:

```
(every3rd '())
=> '()

(every3rd '(a))
=> '(a)

(every3rd '(a b))
=> '(a)

(every3rd '(a b c))
=> '(a)

(every3rd '(a b c d))
=> '(a d)

(every3rd '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p))
=> '(a d g j m p)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Fixing your code (covering the base cases)

It's worth noting that Scheme defines a number of `c[ad]+r` functions, so you can use `(cdddr list)` instead of `(cdr (cdr (cdr list)))`:

```
(cdddr '(a b c d e f g h i))
;=> (d e f g h i)
```

Your code, as others have already pointed out, has the problem that it doesn't consider all of the base cases.  As I see it, you have two base cases, and the second has two sub-cases:

- if the list is empty, there are no elements to take at all, so you can only return the empty list.
- if the list is non-empty, then there's at least one element to take, and you need to take it.  However, when you recurse, there are two possibilies:

  - there are enough elements (three or more) and you can take the `cdddr` of the list; or
  - there are not enough elements, and the element that you took should be the last.

If you assume that `<???>` can somehow handle both of the subcases, then you can have this general structure:

```
(define (every3rd list)
  (if (null? list)
      '()
      (cons (car list) <???>)))
```

Since you already know how to handle the empty list case,  I think that a useful approach here is to blur the distinction between the two subcases, and simply say: "recurse on `x` where `x` is the `cdddr` of the list if it has one, and the empty list if it doesn't."  It's easy enough to write a function `maybe-cdddr` that returns "the `cdddr` of a list if it has one, and the empty list if it doesn't":

```
(define (maybe-cdddr list)
  (if (or (null? list)
          (null? (cdr list))
          (null? (cddr list)))
      '()
      (cdddr list)))
```

```
> (maybe-cdddr '(a b c d))
(d)
> (maybe-cdddr '(a b c))
()
> (maybe-cdddr '(a b))
()
> (maybe-cdddr '(a))
()
> (maybe-cdddr '())
()
```

Now you can combine these to get:

```
(define (every3rd list)
  (if (null? list)
      '()
      (cons (car list) (every3rd (maybe-cdddr list)))))
```

```
> (every3rd '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p))
(a d g j m)
```

### A more modular approach

It's often easier to solve the more general problem first.  In this case, that's taking each *n<sup>th</sup>* element from a list:

```
(define (take-each-nth list n)
  ;; Iterate down the list, accumulating elements 
  ;; anytime that i=0.  In general, each
  ;; step decrements i by 1, but when i=0, i
  ;; is reset to n-1.
  (let recur ((list list) (i 0))
    (cond ((null? list) '())
          ((zero? i)    (cons (car list) (recur (cdr list) (- n 1))))
          (else         (recur (cdr list) (- i 1))))))
```

```
> (take-each-nth '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p) 2)
(a c e g i k m o)

> (take-each-nth '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p) 5)
(a f k p)
```

Once you've done that, it's easy to define the more particular case:

```
(define (every3rd list)
  (take-each-nth list 3))
```

```
> (every3rd '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p))
(a d g j m)
```

This has the advantage that you can now more easily improve the general case and maintain the same interface `every3rd` without having to make any changes.  For instance, the implementation of `take-each-nth` uses some stack space in the recursive, but non-tail call in the second case.  By using an accumulator, we can built the result list in reverse order, and return it when we reach the end of the list:

```
(define (take-each-nth list n)
  ;; This loop is like the one above, but uses an accumulator
  ;; to make all the recursive calls in tail position.  When 
  ;; i=0, a new element is added to results, and i is reset to
  ;; n-1.  If i≠0, then i is decremented and nothing is added 
  ;; to the results.  When the list is finally empty, the
  ;; results are returned in reverse order.
  (let recur ((list list) (i 0) (results '()))
    (cond ((null? list) (reverse results))
          ((zero? i)    (recur (cdr list) (- n 1) (cons (car list) results)))
          (else         (recur (cdr list) (- i 1) results)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `(null? '())` is true. you can debug what's happening with following code

```
(define (every3rd lst)
 (if (begin 
      (display lst)
      (newline)
      (or (null? lst)            
        (null? (cdr lst))))
  '()                        
  (cons (car lst)            
        (every3rd (cdr(cdr(cdr lst)))))))

(every3rd '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p))
(newline)    
(display (cdr '(p)))
(newline)
(display (null? '()))
(newline)
(display (null? (cdr '(p))))
(newline)
```

this gives following result.

```
(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p)
(d e f g h i j k l m n o p)
(g h i j k l m n o p)
(j k l m n o p)
(m n o p)
(p)

()
#t
#t
```