# how to fix this error: "The object (1 3 5) is not applicable" in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am new to Scheme, and I am learning SICP now. I write some code for Exercise 2.20, to return a list whose element shares the same parity with the first one:

```
(define (same-parity first . rest)
    (define (same-parity-iter ret rest)
        (if (null? rest)
            ret
            ((if (odd? (+ first (car rest)))
                 (same-parity-iter ret (cdr rest))
             (same-parity-iter (append ret (list (car rest))) (cdr rest))))))
    (same-parity-iter (list first) (cdr rest)))
```

and run it with some example:

```
(same-parity 1 2 3 4 5)
```

then there is the error:

```
The object (1 3 5) is not applicable.
```

Do you know how to fix this error? I guess it treats the return value (1 3 5) as a function, but have no idea how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: You have too many open parentheses on line 5. That means the return value of the recursive call gets treated as a function.

Comment: Probable duplicate of [The object ___ is not applicable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22976298/1281433).  `(x y)` is a function call.  When you have `((if ...) ...)` you're trying to call whatever `(if ...)` returns as a function.  `(if ...)` returns `(1 3 5)`, and you're trying to call it as a function.

Comment: By the way, searching on Google for `"the object" "is not applicable" site:stackoverflow.com` turned up that duplicate as well as a bunch of others that probably could have solved your problem.  It's generally a good debugging tip to through the specific error message (but usually without the specific data (in this case `(1 3 5)`)) into a search engine first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `(` too much in your code. Have a look at the second `if`:

```
((if (odd? (+ first (car rest)))
     (same-parity-iter ret (cdr rest))
     (same-parity-iter (append ret (list (car rest))) (cdr rest)))))
```

Basically, you are telling the interpreter (or compiler): take the result of the

```
(if (odd? (+ first (car rest)))
     (same-parity-iter ...)
     (same-parity-iter ...))
```

and apply it as a function. The result is a list of integers, which is not a function -- hence the error. Change the code to

```
(define (same-parity first . rest)
  (define (same-parity-iter ret rest)
    (if (null? rest)
        ret
        (if (odd? (+ first (car rest)))
            (same-parity-iter ret (cdr rest))
            (same-parity-iter (append ret (list (car rest))) (cdr rest)))))
    (same-parity-iter (list first) (cdr rest)))
```