# Must the first argument to `eval` be a list?

Tags: list, scheme, racket

*The Scheme Programming Language* says

> procedure: `(eval obj environment)`
>
> returns: values of the Scheme expression represented by `obj` in
>   environment
>
> libraries: `(rnrs eval)`
>
> If `obj` does not represent a syntactically valid expression, `eval`
>   raises an exception with condition type `&syntax`. The environments
>   returned by `environment`, `scheme-report-environment`, and
>   `null-environment` are immutable. Thus, `eval` also raises an
>   exception with condition type `&syntax` if an assignment to any of the
>   variables in the environment appears within the expression.
>
> ```
> (define cons 'not-cons)
> (eval '(let ([x 3]) (cons x 4)) (environment '(rnrs)))   (3 . 4)
> (define lambda 'not-lambda)
> (eval '(lambda (x) x) (environment '(rnrs)))   #<procedure>
> (eval '(cons 3 4) (environment))  exception
> ```

Must the first argument `obj` to `eval` be a list?

Answer (score 2):

No, atoms can also be evaluated. For example, in Racket:

```
#!r6rs

(import (rnrs base (6))
        (rnrs eval (6))
        (rnrs io simple (6)))

(define env (environment '(rnrs)))

(display (eval 42 env))
=> 42
(display (eval #t env))
=> #t
(display (eval "xyz" env))
=> "xyz"
```

Comment: what can be the first argument to `eval`?

Comment: As stated in the docs: any _syntactically valid expression_ in Scheme. Basically lists and atoms. If we go beyond the standard, in Racket we can also `eval` vectors, hashes, etc.

Comment: What are atoms in Scheme? Is atom  a concept of Racket only?

Comment: No, it's a loosely-defined Lisp concept. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12609803/201359) and its comments.