# How do I check to see if something is an Atom in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm looking for the [pedantic](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pedantic) way to test whether something is an [Atom](https://clojure.org/reference/atoms) or not, such as an `(atom? ...)` predicate in Clojure, similar to the family of `(number? ...)`, `(string? ...)`, `(vector? ...)`, etc.

Given Atoms are a main language feature of Clojure, created with [`(atom ...)`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/atom), it feels wrong that I'd have to write my own custom function to test for an internal implementation class.  e.g.,

```
(defn atom? [a] (= (type a) clojure.lang.Atom))
```

Is there more correct paradigm or built-in language feature I'm missing?

---

Note: this question is unrelated and not the same as Scheme's "atoms", [`(atom? ...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609803/what-are-considered-atoms-in-scheme), which are non-null cos-pairs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use `(instance? clojure.lang.Atom a)` and not even bother writing a predicate.

I would also caution that if you feel the need to write code that is conditional on the type of an object at runtime, you might want to take a step back and think of a different way to solve the problem: perhaps protocols or multi-methods would let you dispatch on the object type in a more idiomatic manner?

Comment: Much cleaner implementation without an `atom?` predicate available, thanks.  Also, very good general cautionary advice to follow!  (I was chasing down a problem where upstream code was sometimes passing a prematurely dereferenced value and wanted to catch it in action.) Thank you for your code and insights.

Comment: But that is the way if you want to right a spec, right?

Answer (score -1):

I have written many functions just like that one.  I think that is the best solution.